# Dual boot on separate drives won't work

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, grub

I've Windows 10 installed on my SSD (Disk 0 in image) and my goal was to install Linux on the HDD (disk 1) to boot the device with either of the OS via grub loader. 
I installed Linux on the HDD, however, I don't have a boot manager to choose the OS to start the device with. It loads with Windows by default and there's no option for Linux in the BIOS boot sequence setting.
How can I configure it? 
BIOS mode: UEFI

Screenshot of Windows Disk Management:
[image: Screenshot of Windows Disk Management]

Comment: Some information is missing, as you can't install Linux without it installing GRUB as the bootloader

Answer (score 0):

You can choose another device to boot from by going to Settings > System > Recovery > Advanced startup > Restart now and then choosing a disk.

I'm curious how you "installed" Linux without a bootloader. I would advise flashing an image onto a USB and booting into it instead. Depending on your distribution, it should walk you through properly installing it.

If you want to permanently boot into GRUB so you can select your OS from it, you need to change your default boot entry in your UEFI, which you can also access from advanced startup. Your UEFI will be different depending on your motherboard manufacturer, but it usually isn't to difficult to find where to change boot entries.